# Spring boot and RAML

Tags: maven, spring-boot, raml

I tried to build and run this project
https://github.com/adorsys/raml-springboot-example

I build the project as right click and Maven install.That time raml-springboot-impl.jar is not generating under raml-springboot-impl project.
Do you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to type or copy+paste the following commands in the terminal/bash as shown in the git repos README.md:

*(I'll post my example from Mac, you'll probably have to modify it sensibly)*

- cd to the repo-s root:

`cd /Users/username/Documents/RAML/raml-springboot-example`

- generate the package:

`mvn clean package`

- run project:

`java -jar raml-springboot-impl/target/raml-springboot-impl.jar`

- Create a new Todo:

`curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "task": "Design the API", "priority": 1 }' localhost:8080/api/todos`

- List all Todos

`curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' localhost:8080/api/todos`

- Get one Todo by id

`curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' localhost:8080/api/todos/1`

If you feel more comfortable if you can see stuff in the browser, you can just paste the last two links in Chrome or whatever you're using ;)

Also, you can try https://www.getpostman.com/ for testing endpoints that accept other than 'GET' requests (like the first one here) ;)